# SAPUI5 css: change color of blue border around active ui element

Tags: html, css, user-interface, sapui5, border

UI elements in SAPUI5 have this blue border around them when in focus / active. Any idea how to change the color of that border in css?

Example: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Select/sample/sap.m.sample.Select

The select box and also the selected item have that blue border.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

These are the classes that make that border for active / focus states. You can change the outline color by overriding it as you prefer.

```
html.sap-desktop .sapMSelectListItemBase:focus::after,
.sapMSltPicker-CTX .sapMSelectListItemBaseSelected::after,
.sapMComboBoxBasePicker-CTX .sapMSelectListItemBaseSelected::after
```

Example:

```
html.sap-desktop .sapMSelectListItemBase:focus::after,
.sapMSltPicker-CTX .sapMSelectListItemBaseSelected::after,
.sapMComboBoxBasePicker-CTX .sapMSelectListItemBaseSelected::after {

  outline: 0.125rem solid red;

}
```

Sometimes you should use override the previous styles because you are using an existing UI package.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good already, but maybe one more thing. originally the blue border of the dropdown is still visible when you just click on it (without opening it). would this also be possible? or maybe in general for all elements like input fields, button etc.